# My server virtual memory full

Tags: php, ssd, swap, webmin, virtualmin

occasionally my server hits 100% usage on virtual memory and I don't know if that is something alarming or not? ( this happends gradualy to fill to that percent over 1-2 weeks from clean swap)

I usually resolve this issue like this:

```
swapoff -a && swapon -a
```

do you suggest any other method of resolving this?

I tried to see what is in swap and clearly it's `php-cgi` or each sites processes that runs on my server..

after I run this:

```
for file in /proc/*/status ; do awk '/VmSwap|Name/{printf $2 " " $3}END{ print ""}' $file; done | sort -k 2 -n -r | less
```

I get this result:

```
miniserv.pl 17096 kB
php-cgi7.0 15732 kB
php-cgi7.0 15532 kB
php-cgi7.0 13768 kB
php-cgi7.0 13532 kB
php-cgi7.0 13300 kB
php-cgi7.0 12056 kB
php-cgi7.0 11004 kB
php-cgi7.0 9636 kB
php-cgi7.0 4712 kB
php-cgi7.0 3700 kB
php-cgi7.0 3600 kB
php-cgi7.0 3288 kB
php-cgi7.0 3100 kB
php-cgi7.0 3084 kB
php-cgi7.0 3040 kB
php-cgi7.0 2824 kB
php-cgi7.0 2756 kB
(sd-pam) 2580 kB
php-cgi7.0 2524 kB
php-cgi7.0 2524 kB
(sd-pam) 2280 kB
(sd-pam) 2192 kB
php-loop.pl 2076 kB
php-loop.pl 2076 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
php-loop.pl 2072 kB
(sd-pam) 2036 kB
php-loop.pl 1976 kB
php-loop.pl 1964 kB
php-loop.pl 1964 kB
php-loop.pl 1964 kB
php-loop.pl 1960 kB
php-loop.pl 1956 kB
php-loop.pl 1956 kB
php-loop.pl 1948 kB
php-loop.pl 1940 kB
php-loop.pl 1920 kB
php-loop.pl 1908 kB
php-loop.pl 1908 kB
php-loop.pl 1904 kB
php-loop.pl 1872 kB
```

Comment: It is normal for OS to swap out unused code

Comment: ok, do you suggest to do what I do now,, or not,, or maybe I don't have to do this `swapoff -a && swapon -a` at all,, would OS be fine to do maintanance on it's own?

Comment: You definitely don't need to switch swap off/on. It is good to have unused code swapped out as it frees much more valuable RAM.

Comment: not your virtual memory, but your physical memory.

Comment: ok thanks for help guys,, I have much free SYS memory but I will stop to do that switching on/off for now and see how server goes from that..

Comment: If you have a lot of free memory you can tune swappiness to get a bit of performance boost. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swappiness

Comment: yeah,,did that already ;)

Comment: Was going through this same issue with my 4GB RAM 256MB virtual memory server and I was worried since there was just one fresh wordpress site on the server until I read this: https://www.linuxatemyram.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question about swap, virtual memory it's sum of (RAM+Swap)*over-commitment. You could read more on in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Virtual_memory).

You have problem with swap. I don't know why, but all Linux always swaps, and you couldn't do anythything. In your case, if you don't want use swap, you could increase `vm.overcommit_ratio` to prevent problems with Virtual Memory and remove swap at all.

Comment: I will mark this,, I ended up removed swap completely and I think that will cover it for now,, I have strange feeling that this "newer" SSD disks are messing up something about swap, thanks

Comment: Hello swap does not work with HD SSD so I was running these errors it is recommended to completely disable the swap memory.

Comment: @PauloBoaventura what you mean under `swap does not work with HD SSD`?